# 400 Bad Request when i register a new user in NodeJS via Mongoose using PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

Am creating a registration form where user needs to enter details of his emailid(username),password,DOB,Address,phoneno. All fields are mandatory here emailid acts as an username. I have designed my Mongoose Schema

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

 var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    phoneno: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true
   },
   Address : {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   Dob: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   }
 },{
   timestamps: true
 });

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

My user router is given below

```
var express = require('express');
var UserDetails = express.Router();
var userSchema=require('../models/user');
var passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Verify    = require('./verify');

UserDetails.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
var newUser = new userSchema({
    username : req.body.email,
    Dob : req.body.dob,
    Address : req.body.address,
    phoneno : req.body.phoneno
 });
userSchema.register(newUser,req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({err: err});
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(res);
        return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
    });
 });
});
```

This is the json object am sending via PostMan

```
 {"email":"kannaa.in","password": "abcdef","phoneno":96930,"address":"396 SM Road","dob":"14-05-1992"}
```

But in the console and postman it says bad request if i try to perform the operation.However it stores the value in DB. I couldn't find out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after no one answered i found out myself what is the error about PassportJS expects the request to contain req.body.username it doesn't matter how many other datas you send it needs req.body.username from the request side. So all i had to change was rather than email i set it as username in postman and it worked like charm.

My postman Data

```
{"username":"kannaa.in","password": "abcdef","phoneno":96930,"address":"396 SM Road","dob":"14-05-1992"}
```